# Display embedded templates inside a conditional statement if checked on publish page

Tags: conditionals, embeds, checkbox

In short: I need to display embedded templates based on whether they are selected by checkbox on the publish page, but my code doesn't work if more than 1 is checked.

I tried using the code below to check for whether a checkbox was checked and display the template if it was. This works, unless more than one is checked off, then none display because the statement no longer validates as true.

I have one full-page template shared by 2 pages. I have one page that requires Rides, and the other requires all 3 templates.

The name of my checkbox field is choose_entries, and the options are "Rides" "Gear" "Groups".

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" limit="1" url_title="{segment_1}"}
    {if choose_entries == "Rides"}
            <h2 class="section-title">Rides<span class="green"></span></h2>
            {embed="views/.rides"}
            <img src="content/img/bike.png" />
    {/if}
    {if choose_entries == "Gear"}
            <h2 class="section-title">Gear<span class="orange"></span></h2>
            {embed="views/.gear"}
    {/if}
    {if choose_entries == "Groups"}
            <h2 class="section-title">Groups<span class="blue"></span></h2>
            {embed="views/.groups"}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I know there is probably a way to do it with php (but I don't write php), I would like to avoid that if possible. I was unable to find the correct php syntax to get an "if contains" type statement to work.

Comment: So can a single entry have more than one item ticked in the checkbox? Or do you mean that if more than one entry has 'Rides' ticked for instance?

Comment: 1 page can have more than 1 entry checkbox checked to display embedded sections, i.e. the page San Diego can have "Rides" and "Gear" checked to display those embedded templates on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't even attempt to do something like this with the native checkboxes, they're really substandard. Use pixel and tonic's field pack instead and you'll have no problems:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pt-field-pack

Comment: I was using that but hadn't been able to get the syntax working. Turns out I was missing an end quotation mark. Thank you!